# How to get all versions (including invisible ones) in SDKMAN

Tags: sdkman

SDKMan has many more versions then that are shown when doing a 'sdk list'. I would like to see those as well, so I can install older versions. SDKMan's API seems to be selective in what it shows, but I cannot find any documentation on it. Based on inspecting the CLI sources I found these URLs:

To list all candidates, like maven, java, etc:

https://api.sdkman.io/2/candidates/all

To get versions for one candidates for one platform (e.g. maven on windows):

https://api.sdkman.io/2/candidates/maven/win/versions/all

The problem is some candidates, most notably java, do not return possible versions in that url. The response is empty.

What am I doing wrong or missing? How can I get all versions for all candidates?

Answer (score 0):

As of https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-candidates/blob/master/conf/routes java seems to be a special case.

At https://api.sdkman.io/2/candidates/java/linuxx64/versions/list?installed= I get a list of versions.

You can look up the platforms in https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-candidates/blob/master/app/utils/Platform.scala

Comment: What happens is that all the rendering is done server side. The versions API returns not a JSON response but a rendered one.  The client basically is just a wrapper around curl. And there is no way to tell it to return all the versions that it knows of. It only shows the last LTS and the newest.  IOW the answer to this question is: it cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have learned, this cannot be done; the API simply does not return the information. But I'd very gladly like to be proven wrong.